# How to create a service for git bash and adding all the c drive files and then commit

Tags: powershell, git

I have written the power shell script which creates the service for git bash. After opening git bash the script has to add all the c drive files and commit. but for every one hour what ever the changes takes place in the c drive like if we install software some files will be created that updation  has to be taken place in the script.

```
$serviceName = "MyService"

if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    $serviceToRemove = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='$serviceName'"
    $serviceToRemove.delete()
    "service removed"
}
else
{
    "service does not exists"
}

"Installing service"


$binaryPath = "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
New-Service -name $serviceName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -displayName $serviceName -startupType Automatic -credential $mycreds

"Installation completed"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you want to version control your entire system disk, and do so using git metadata? you know that each commit in git is a full copy of the project, right? each time you run it, you are doubling the size of the VC'd data. There are many other software options for backups and versioning, and coupled with git's difficulties with large files, this seems like an approach that could use some rethinking. ...and why the service?

Comment: Sir i have to implement the script which starts the git bash service and add the c-drive files in the git folder. If any software is installed then some additional files will be added in c drive so that additional files also be included in git folder. Is their is any way to implement this thing in scripting like power-shell script or batch script if so please give information regarding this i am thankful to you.

Comment: Only programs which conform to a specific interface can run as a service. Git Bash almost certainly cannot. Look into Task Scheduler instead. // Also, do not do this. It will not work in a meaningful way because many files are exclusively locked.

Comment: Sir is their any tool for monitoring git version control like monitoring git for every one hour whether to check any files are added after installing any software.

Comment: if you did this, you would double the size of the data on the hard disk every hour. that said, using task scheduler should work fine for starting a task every hour.

Comment: **_why on EARTH are you creating an awkward, peculiar backup system instead of using a real, reliable one?_**